# EKEvent calendarItemExternalIdentifier: for exchange

Tags: ios, swift, macos, ekevent

Right now we are using the calendarItemExternalIdentifier property of an EKEvent to access the same event or reminder across multiple devices. But We are having trouble with exchange events, the identifier changes between mac and iOS.

Any ideas on how I can access the same exchange event between devices?

Comment: This difference is mentioned in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/eventkit/ekcalendaritem/1507283-calendaritemexternalidentifier), but what did you end up doing for this? I was thinking you could append a UUID to the end of the `EKCalendarItem.notes`.

Comment: What did you end up doing?